# Entity with string for primary key, is automatically given a shadow key

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

In my upgrade from .net core 3.1 to .net 6, I run in the following problem with the string primary key of my entity.

```c
public class Country
{
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The entity is configured with `CountryCode` as key:

```c
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().HasKey(c => c.CountryCode);
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().Property(c => c.CountryCode).ValueGeneratedNever();
```

Country can be related to other entities, such as Company:

```c
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

With the relationship being configured as:

```c
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasOne<Country>(c => c.Country).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.CountryCode);
```

In .net core 3.1 this worked well, however in .net 6 the `Country` entity is created with a shadow key: `TempId1`.

```c
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Countries",
    columns: table => new
    {
        CountryCode = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
        Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
        TempId1 = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Countries", x => x.CountryCode);
        table.UniqueConstraint("AK_Countries_TempId1", x => x.TempId1);
    });
```

From below comments by Ivan Stoev, I understand now this is related to nullable reference type functionality in c# 8.0 and above.  I tried to ensure to EF Core that the PK will not be null by ensuring CountryCode cannot be set to null in code:

```c
public string CountryCode { get; set; } = null!;
```

But this had no effect on the shadow key.

Comment: `Country` has no `TempId1`, however it does have `TempId` (w/o suffix)? Most probably it's something related to nullability, in case you have NRT enabled in net6.0 project, it might change the assumption of the nullability of the FKs, and even associate automatically another one (suffix `1` , `2` etc. indicates auto generated property/column name).

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks.  What does the abbreviation NRT stand for?  I can't find any reference to it with the usual search engines.  As I wrote, in 3.1 this temporary id was not created for my entity.  So this must be something specific to later versions?

Comment: [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types). The column and unique constraint smell like one-to-one relationship, check for other entity having `HasOne` / `HasPrincipalKey` calls with `Country`.

Comment: I rephrased the question, since the issue is really not related to the seed data.

Comment: When I create a brand new project with the entities configured exactly like my current question, the shadow key is not created.  I will investigate further, there must be some additional property on 1 of the entities that causes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the relationship to `Company` only.  The entity `Company` also had a complex object  for `Address` which also included a reference to `Country`.

I had configured this property to be ignored during my testing with:

```c
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().Ignore(v => v.Address);
```

However this configuration did not actually prevent it from being evaluated.  When I commented out the property `Address` on `Company`, the shadow key on `Country` no longer was created.

Thanks to Ivan Stoev for pointing me in the right direction.